# mysql sum and show all registries

Tags: mysql, sum

im trying to sum and show all registries in mysql.
i have this query:

```
select `deliverables`.*, 
       `users`.`first_name`, 
       `users`.`last_name` 
from `deliverables` 
inner join `users` on `users`.`id` = `deliverables`.`user_id` 
where `deliverables`.`specialty_id` = '11' and 
      `deliverables`.`role_id` <> '1'
```

and the output is:

```
file_code  file_name       dedicated_hours

0001asder  test-file.docx  4
0001as234w asdf.doc        2
jgfjh2546  test.docx       4
0001asder  test-file.docx  1
0001asder  test-file.docx  0
0001asder  test-file.docx  0
```

i need sum the dedicated_hours where file_code is equal so it should looks like this:

```
file_code  file_name       dedicated_hours  sum

0001asder  test-file.docx  4                5
0001as234w asdf.doc        2                2
jgfjh2546  test.docx       4                4
0001asder  test-file.docx  1                5
0001asder  test-file.docx  0                5
0001asder  test-file.docx  0                5
```

im using sum(dedicated_hours) and group by file_code but it only show:

```
file_code  file_name       dedicated_hours  sum

0001asder  test-file.docx  4                5
0001as234w asdf.doc        2                2
jgfjh2546  test.docx       4                4
```

How can i sum and show all registries at the same time?

Comment: @MartinParkin no it won't work. check again. he does not want to aggregate the results into a single row.

Comment: @user995691 What is your MySQL serve version ? Can you upgrade to latest version (8.0.2 and above) ?

Comment: I'm confused then.  How can the SUM be 1 for 3 identical results and 5 for another?

Comment: @MartinParkin yeah that's a valid question. Expected output does not seem correct.

Comment: sorry my bad i edited the output

Comment: @user995691 please inform about the MySQL server version you have and possibility of upgradation (if any) ?

Comment: MySql version 5.0.12

Comment: @user995691 does the posted answer work ? Please provide feedback. If it works, please consider marking it as accepted answer. Please see: [How to accept an answer for closure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your MySQL version (5.0.12) does not support [Window Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html) (it should be a decent incentive enough to upgrade to get the latest goodies :)

Nevertheless, we can use a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) to determine the aggregated `SUM()` for a `file_code` separately. Then, we can simply Join back to the main tables, to show the sum column.

```
SELECT 
  d.file_code,
  d.file_name, 
  d.dedicated_hours,  
  dt.sum, 
  u.first_name, 
  u.last_name 
FROM deliverables AS d 
JOIN users AS u 
  ON u.id = d.user_id 
JOIN
(
  SELECT file_code, 
         SUM(dedicated_hours) AS sum 
   WHERE speciality_id = '11' AND 
         role_id <> '1'
   GROUP BY file_code
) AS dt 
  ON dt.file_code = d.file_code
WHERE d.speciality_id = '11' AND 
      d.role_id <> '1'
```

---

[MySQL 8.0.2 and above](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-2-introducing-window-functions/) solution would be simply using [`SUM(..) OVER (..)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum)

```
SELECT 
  d.file_code,
  d.file_name, 
  d.dedicated_hours,  
  SUM(d.dedicated_hours) OVER (PARTITION BY d.file_code) AS sum, 
  u.first_name, 
  u.last_name 
FROM deliverables AS d 
JOIN users AS u 
  ON u.id = d.user_id 
WHERE d.speciality_id = '11' AND 
      d.role_id <> '1'
```